# Garbage collection notifications

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, weak-references, finalizer

Firstly, apologies for the length of this question, but I want to explain myself fully from the outset.

OK, a bit of background. I've been working on some code that implements the Weak Event pattern using the `WeakReference` object. In doing so I ran into the usual problem of objects being leaked in certain scenarios where a publisher stops raising events. If you are interested then there's a fair bit of [information](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29922/Weak-Events-in-C) on the pattern out there. The WPF team implemented the [WeakEventManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.weakeventmanager.aspx) to tackle the problem which I believe uses a scheduler to check for any leaked objects and gets rid of them.

I decided to try a different approach. Instead of using a scheduler I wanted to trigger the detection and unsubscription of leaked objects using garbage collections. This seems logical to me as the targets of any `WeakReference` objects are only dropped as a result of collections. This then led me to code up something which would raise an event when a garbage collection had taken place. Firstly I looked into using the framework's `GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification` mechanism but quickly realised it wasn't feasible as it [cannot be used with concurrent garbage collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713687.aspx). Then I did a fair bit of reading on the topic and found Jeffrey Richter's [solution](http://wintellect.com/blogs/JeffreyR/receiving-notifications-when-garbage-collections-occur) but this has a couple of problems and only alerts you gen0 and gen2 collections

Long story short, I build the following simple class. The purpose of this class is to generate event notifications that a garbage collection has occurred. However, the mechanism for generating these notifications is based on the finalization of a detector object. As such, the events are NOT raised when a garbage collection is taking place but afterwards when the finalizer thread is run.

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class responsible for monitoring garbage collections.
    /// </summary>
    public static class GarbageCollectionMonitor
    {
        private static readonly object syncLock;
        private static int generation0CollectionCount;
        private static EventHandler<EventArgs> generation0Subscriptions;
        private static int generation1CollectionCount;
        private static EventHandler<EventArgs> generation1Subscriptions;
        private static int generation2CollectionCount;
        private static EventHandler<EventArgs> generation2Subscriptions;

        public static event EventHandler<EventArgs> Generation0GarbageCollected
        {
            add
            {
                lock (GarbageCollectionMonitor.syncLock)
                {
                    GarbageCollectionMonitor.generation0Subscriptions = (EventHandler<EventArgs>)Delegate.Combine(  GarbageCollectionMonitor.generation0Subscriptions,
                                                                                                                    value);
                }
            }

            remove
            {
                lock (GarbageCollectionMonitor.syncLock)
                {
                    GarbageCollectionMonitor.generation0Subscriptions = (EventHandler<EventArgs>)Delegate.Remove(   GarbageCollectionMonitor.generation0Subscriptions,
                                                                                                                    value);
                }
            }
        }

        public static event EventHandler<EventArgs> Generation1GarbageCollected
        {
            add
            {
                lock (GarbageCollectionMonitor.syncLock)
                {
                    GarbageCollectionMonitor.generation1Subscriptions = (EventHandler<EventArgs>)Delegate.Combine(  GarbageCollectionMonitor.generation1Subscriptions,
                                                                                                                    value);
                }
            }

            remove
            {
                lock (GarbageCollectionMonitor.syncLock)
                {
                    GarbageCollectionMonitor.generation1Subscriptions = (EventHandler<EventArgs>)Delegate.Remove(   GarbageCollectionMonitor.generation1Subscriptions,
                                                                                                                    value);
                }
            }
        }

        public static event EventHandler<EventArgs> Generation2GarbageCollected
        {
            add
            {
                lock (GarbageCollectionMonitor.syncLock)
                {
                    GarbageCollectionMonitor.generation2Subscriptions = (EventHandler<EventArgs>)Delegate.Combine(  GarbageCollectionMonitor.generation2Subscriptions,
                                                                                                                    value);
                }
            }

            remove
            {
                lock (GarbageCollectionMonitor.syncLock)
                {
                    GarbageCollectionMonitor.generation2Subscriptions = (EventHandler<EventArgs>)Delegate.Remove(   GarbageCollectionMonitor.generation2Subscriptions,
                                                                                                                    value);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs the garbage collection monitor type
        /// </summary>
        static GarbageCollectionMonitor()
        {
            GarbageCollectionMonitor.syncLock = new object();

            // Construct a detector object
            //
            // N.B. No reference to the detector is held so that it can immediately be
            // collected by the garbage collector.
            new Detector();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Class responsible for detecting the operation of the garbage collector
        /// via its finalization method
        /// </summary>
        private sealed class Detector
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Constructs a detector object
            /// </summary>
            public Detector()
            {
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Finalizes a detector object
            /// </summary>
            ~Detector()
            {
                // Get the generation 0 collection count
                //
                // Since the finalizer thread is frozen when the garbage collector is
                // operating there is no danger of race conditions when retrieving the
                // garbage collection counts
                int generation0CollectionCount = GC.CollectionCount(0);

                // Determine if the current generation 0 collection count is greater than
                // the monitor's generation 0 collection count
                //
                // This indicates that a generation 0 garbage collection has taken place
                // since the last time a detector object was finalized.
                if (generation0CollectionCount > GarbageCollectionMonitor.generation0CollectionCount)
                {
                    // Update the monitor's generation 0 collection count to the current
                    // collection count
                    GarbageCollectionMonitor.generation0CollectionCount = generation0CollectionCount;

                    // Process any generation 0 event subscriptions
                    this.ProcessSubscriptions(GarbageCollectionMonitor.generation0Subscriptions);
                }

                int generation1CollectionCount = GC.CollectionCount(1);

                if (generation1CollectionCount > GarbageCollectionMonitor.generation1CollectionCount)
                {
                    GarbageCollectionMonitor.generation1CollectionCount = generation1CollectionCount;

                    this.ProcessSubscriptions(GarbageCollectionMonitor.generation1Subscriptions);
                }

                int generation2CollectionCount = GC.CollectionCount(2);

                if (generation2CollectionCount > GarbageCollectionMonitor.generation2CollectionCount)
                {
                    GarbageCollectionMonitor.generation2CollectionCount = generation2CollectionCount;

                    this.ProcessSubscriptions(GarbageCollectionMonitor.generation2Subscriptions);
                }

                // Construct a new generation 0 detector object
                new Detector();
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Processes event subscriptions
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="subscriptions">The subscriptions</param>
            private void ProcessSubscriptions(EventHandler<EventArgs> subscriptions)
            {
                // N.B. A local reference to the subscriptions delegate is required because
                // this method is run on the finalizer thread which is started AFTER the
                // garbage collector has finished running. As a result it is likely that
                // the application threads that were frozen by the garbage collector will
                // have been thawed. Since delegates are immutable, by getting a local
                // reference the processing of the subscriptions is made thread-safe as any
                // attempt by another thread to asynchronously add or remove a subscription
                // will result in a separate new delegate being constructed.

                // Determine if any event subscriptions need to be invoked
                //
                // N.B. If a local reference were not used then there would be a risk of
                // the following:
                //
                // (1) The null reference inequality check yields a true result.
                // (2) The finalizer thread is paused.
                // (3) Another thread removes all subscriptions to the event causing the
                // subscriptions delegate to be replaced with a null reference.
                // (4) The finalizer thread is unpaused.
                // (5) The attempt to invoke the subscriptions delegate results in a null
                // reference exception being thrown.
                if (subscriptions != null)
                {
                    // Invoke the event
                    subscriptions.Invoke(   this,
                                            EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to work well but when testing it with the following code...

```
    private void Gen0GarbageCollected(  object sender,
                                        System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Gen0  " + GC.CollectionCount(0) + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private void Gen1GarbageCollected(  object sender,
                                        System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Gen1  " + GC.CollectionCount(1) + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private void Gen2GarbageCollected(  object sender,
                                        System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("Gen2  " + GC.CollectionCount(2) + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

...I get the following results

```
    Gen0    1
    Gen0    2
    Gen1    1
    Gen0    3
    Gen0    4
    Gen1    2
    Gen2    1
    Gen0    5
    Gen1    3
    Gen2    2
    Gen0    7
    Gen0    8
    Gen0    9
    Gen1    4
    Gen0    10
    Gen0    11
    Gen0    12
    Gen1    5
    Gen2    3
    Gen0    14
    Gen0    15
    Gen0    16
    Gen1    6
    Gen0    17
```

It seems that not all garbage collections are triggering the finalization thread. In this example the 6th and 13th collections of generation 0 are not raising events.

Now (finally) comes the question.

I'm baffled by this and need to understand why it is happening. My reasoning is that since there is no guarantee when the finalizer thread will run it is possible that multiple garbage collections (of any generation) may occur between instances of the finalizer thread being run.

If this is the case then the only guarantee that can be given is that if an event is raised then a garbage collection of that generation has taken place since the last time the event was raised.

That's the best I can come up with but I would really appreciate if someone with more knowledge of garbage collection internals could confirm if it is correct and I don't have huge implementation error in my solution.

Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: I'm loath to type this up as an answer because I'm only touching up on an assumption of yours. When the GC runs, and finds an object to collect, if it has a finalizer it is put on the freachable list, which removes it from GC, *making it ineligible for collection*. So when the finalizer runs, GC has in fact not fully executed on that object, it has only noticed it, put it aside for further processing. Only after the finalizer has executed, and on the next GC, will the object actually be collected. Not sure this does anything to your question though.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that the code Richter posted cannot be modified to report Gen1 collections, but it would need some trickery, and would probably not catch them all.

Comment: And yes, the finalizer thread plods along finalizing objects on the freachable list, at its own pace. It does not only run between collections, so you will not catch all collections using this technique alone. May I ask *why* you need to catch garbage collections? For the problem you described, do you really need to react to *every* garbage collection cycle?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen "Also, I'm not sure that the code Richter posted cannot be modified to report Gen1 collections, but it would need some trickery, and would probably not catch them all." I spent all day yesterday playing around with it and got it to a state where it reported gen1 collections. However, the code was way more complex than the sample I posted here and more unreliable due to various issues with reregistering approach.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen "For the problem you described, do you really need to react to every garbage collection cycle?" No, you are right, I don't need to be notified of every collection. I'm just curious as to the reason and want to make sure there's not a huge conceptual hole in my logic.

Comment: Remember that finalizers can, and do, allocate memory, which in turn can provoke a new garbage collection cycle. So no, you cannot react to *every* cycle with this approach.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen _"Remember that finalizers can, and do, allocate memory, which in turn can provoke a new garbage collection cycle."_ Good point. Hadn't considered that. Appreciate you thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: I don't get why you are pursuing this.  You already know that the finalizer isn't useful to you to get notifications, no point in continuing on this path.

Comment: @Hans Passant The finalizer is useful for my purposes since, as Lasse noted, it's not critical that I be notified of every single collection in order to effectively clean up leaked weak event subscriptions. The approach works fine for the usage scenario outlined. I agree that it isn't ideal since garbage collection and finalization are two separate processes. However, they are strongly related and this the best mechanism I could come up with. Would be very interested if you could suggest a better approach.

Comment: If you are doing this only to clean up weak references then it isn't at all critical that this is done in sync with collections.  Can't you just do it when you add a new one?  Or use a plain timer?

Comment: @Hans Passant What if a new one doesn't get added? What do you set the timer interval to? These triggers are unconnected to the mechanism that releases the weak references and IMHO are a worse cludge than using the finalizer approach. At least finalizers are coupled to the garbage collection process. Anyway, this is all by-the-by; the usage scenario isn't really important. The question was more about the interaction between the GC and the finalization thread. It's not critical, the solution works fine, I was just curious and wanted to make sure I hadn't misunderstood something important.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a [`ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757.aspx), where the key is the object you want to monitor for cleanup and the value is a specially-crafted [`CriticalHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.criticalhandle.aspx) that implements [`ReleaseHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.criticalhandle.releasehandle.aspx) by setting a static Boolean flag in code that means "it's time to clean up the handlers"?

Then you can use a separate timer to launch a thread/task that checks the Boolean flag and, if `true`, runs your manual cleanup (this cleanup would not, and should not, be executed during a finalizer or during the call to `ReleaseHandle`).

Answer (score 0):

There are only two situations where it really matters whether dead weak-event subscriptions get cleaned up:

- Every time the event in question is invoked, the system will waste time processing any dead subscriptions that haven't been cleaned up.
- If an unbounded number of new subscribers can be added without dead subscriptions getting cleaned up, the number of dead subscriptions may grow without bound.

If an event is never invoked and no new subscriptions are added, no time will be spent processing the dead events, and the total amount of memory occupied by the events won't grow.  Consequently, there generally won't be any real harm in just letting them sit.

I would suggest that you may wish to have the code clean up dead events if they are observed during an event invocation, and otherwise either have each subscription request check a couple of weak subscriptions and clean them up if they've died, or else have event subscription requests scan all event subscriptions if the number that have been added since the last scan sufficiently exceeds the number that were found to be alive during that scan.  One may have the code that checks for dead subscriptions monitor the total number of GC cycles that have been performed and skip the checks if the number of GC cycles that have been performed to date equals the number that had been performed before the last scan was started, but it probably doesn't matter too much.